# backslash in CSS min-height property

Tags: css

Hi I've come across the following code: `.height480{ min-height:484px; min-height:497px\9;}` I've never seen the backslash before. I've checked the W3c documentation for min-height and there's no mention of it. Anyone know anything about it? I've noticed that firefox ignores it, so guess it might just be a typo? Cheers Dewd

Comment: @BoltClock. Thanks for identifying this as dupe. A google search for css \ didn't bring up the dupe question, neither did the answer suggestions when I was writing the question. At the time, I wasn't aware of the significance of the number 9. Most numbers in css are arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a IE hack

The first `min-height` work for other browser and next `min-height with slash` will work for IE7, IE8, and IE9

[see this site](http://www.ajaxera.com/ie-hacks-galore/)

```
.header {width:300px;height:200px;background:#000;} /* Applies to all browsers */
*.header {width:310px;height:200px;background:#000;} /* Applies to all IE browsers */
_.header {width:290px;height:200px;background:#000;} /* Applies to all IE browsers 6 and below */
.header {width /*\**/:330px\9;height:200px;background:#000;} /* Applies to IE 8 */
(Note: IE 8 and IE9 are a diffent animals, it is tying to act like web-kit. A tip of the hat to Safari and Crome.)
```

Comment: could you advise specifically what the \9 does? is it stating apply to earlier than IE9? as in \8 would be earlier than IE8? or am I misunderstanding?